# SKSpriteNode Animations

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm making a game and have about 10 different types of sprites who each have a distinct animation when they appear onto the SKScene. I created an animation class that loads all the textures when the app is launched and puts all the textures into a collection. Then those collections are passed to create a collection of animation skactions that will be fetched/ran by all nodes throughout the game. This method allows me to only create one instance of a certain skaction animation instead of making one for each node. It works just fine, but I'm not sure if it is a design structure.

Answer (score 1):

Bearing in mind that animations are memory-expensive and load too slow to do that dynamically, preloading them into memory is a good initial step. This is what I do in my games and the only downside is game loading times may go over 10 seconds on slower devices.